# SQL connector with C++, can fetch the column(TEXT) with more than 15 characters

Tags: c++, sql, connector

I solve it by myself:

Using MySQL++ instead, it's a very powerful library, with no bugs.

Original Problem:

I'm using MySQL Connector C++(1.1.6) to manipulate MySQL Database(Version 5.7.9), the platform I use is VS2015.

Question is, when I tried to fetch the data with more than 15 characters in some 
field in a table. The Program always get crushed in this function.

```
res->getString(1);
```

And more clearly, the crush point occurs in xstring file, from what I see, the program tries to free a null point..

```
15 characters are OK
16 characters yield CRUSH
```

The weird thing is, if I click "continue" 3 times in debug mode, the program will continuously run.

Comment: When the program crashes, do you get any error message?

Comment: Nope, I put the code in the try..catch block but nothing caught.

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: Im using VS2015, boost1.56,Mysql Connector1.1.6, MySQL 5.7.9